# Exhausted all means of WebGL debugging I can think of - still blank screen

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

Thank you to all who helped.

The problems were associated with differing version of gl-matrix that had different method signatures and forgetting to enable the vertex attributes. As expected, the problem would not throw errors, but was an oversight.

---

I have used each of the debugging options I am aware of for WebGL

1. usual program debugging techniques including object inspection / single stepping
2. Chrome extension WebGL Inspector
3. Calls to gl.getError()
4. Khronos webgl-debug.js

None of these techniques have thrown an error. So, I'm at a loss. It is currently programmed to clear to gray (happens) and render a canvas filling white plane. The plane is an indexed element array comprised of 8 triangles. I believe I have inspected the appropriate arrays and found them to be correct.

Only the gray background is drawn. This is both my first javascript and my first webGL but I have extensive history with OpenGL. I have followed multiple sources as my model.

I have donated hundreds of OpenGL examples to the "internet" so the down vote this received within 10 seconds of original posting isn't very equitable. Of course I have researched this. If interested, here's what I donated in the last three months: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BwOeYFxCg1yQcnZKMjlCeHZUU1U&usp=sharing

The end use will be a full screen display on a fixed piece of hardware.

As usual, there must be something simple I have overlooked.

Comment: If you don't get any error, then how do you want us to solve the error?

Comment: One of the basic tenets of debugging - which I teach - is that if you have exhausted all ideas and still have a problem, some assumption you've made is wrong - this is Doyle's Law. Clearly, there is something I have assumed is working which is not. If there were an "error" I would probably have found and fixed it.

Comment: while i disagree with the downvote, this question needs better formatting and less code , please only show the relevant parts: setting up and drawing.

Comment: Good point. I have removed the HTML wrapper and blatantly unrelated javascript.

Comment: Where are the `#version` directives in your shaders?

Comment: They were not found in the books nor samples. I will find an appropriate value and add them now. Thank you for the pointer on that.

Comment: I added #version 100 with no change. The shaders compile and link successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all who helped.

The problems were associated with differing version of gl-matrix that had different method signatures and forgetting to enable the vertex attributes.